# Ubuntu 14.04 installed

Tags: server

New to ubuntu. Have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on stationary pc.
Now I want to install webmin and found thehow to do, but as mentioned I am new to this. It says login to your remote server?????
Can do all the deb adds, update and install etc but nothing happens.
How do log in / find the remote server?

rgds
Birger

Answer (score 0):

Step One—Root Login:

Once you know your IP address and root password, login as the main user, root.

`ssh root@123.45.67.890`

Step Two—Add Webmin to APT repository:

Edit the `/etc/apt/sources.list` file on your system and add the following lines.

Open the file with nano:

`nano /etc/apt/sources.list`

Press [Page Down] button on the keyboard to reach to the end of file. (or press Left ALt+/)
Then paste these two lines below:

```
deb http://download.webmin.com/download/repository sarge contrib
deb http://webmin.mirror.somersettechsolutions.co.uk/repository sarge contrib
```

Step Three—Install Webmin’s GPG key

You should also fetch and install Webmin’s GPG key in which the repository is signed and with the commands:

```
 cd /root
 wget http://www.webmin.com/jcameron-key.asc
 apt-key add jcameron-key.asc
```

Step Four—Install Webmin:

You will now be able to install with the commands:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install webmin
```

Step Five—Login to Webmin:

Open your browser and go to http://your_droplet_ip:10000/

You can now login as root with your root password, or as any user who can use sudo to run commands as root.

reference [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-webmin-on-an-ubuntu-cloud-server)

Also you are asking for remote login,refer [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-ssh-to-connect-to-a-remote-server-in-ubuntu)